# ParametricPlot with DSolve does not show anything

Tags: plotting

I manage to plot strn[t] and sig[t] where sig[t] is the solution from my DSolve. However, when I want to ParametricPlot sig[t] vs strn[t], I failed to do it as the parametric plot does not show anything.

```
strn[t] = t*0.00025;
modulus = 20000;
sol1 = DSolve[{D[strn[t], t] == D[sig[t], t]/modulus, sig[0] == 0}, sig[t], t]
Plot[strn[t], {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[sig[t] /. sol1, {t, 0, 100}]
ParametricPlot[{sig[t] /. sol1, strn[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: You need to use `sig[t] /. First@sol1`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks please post that as an answer.

Comment: Def. a function in the most basic case should look: " f[x_] := ". The underscore is missing. For every numerical value of t in the func strn we get numerical value and the derivative of any number is 0 and I don't really see the need to define a function and then pass an argument - in every case you end up with 0.  Also I think, as a general rule, you should try to use less confusing naming convention for your functions. Are we using Sign[x], the built-in function, or a generic sig[x] function. As for comment above me - plotting it using the rule you mentioned doesn't produce anything.

Comment: Thx for all the help. However, I still cannot plot sig[t] Vs strn[t]. The first two plots show that sig[t] and strn[t] can actually be plotted. Since the range of strn [t] is from 0 to 0.025 while range of sig[t] is from 0 to 500, does it means that parametric plot cannot be used? because so far i see in the help related to plot range, all of the plot using an approximately equal range.

Comment: Your `ParametricPlot` is working, but the aspect ratio is tiny. Try using the option `AspectRatio -> 1`

Comment: @SimonWoods it works! thx!!

Answer (score 2):

Let me first answer why it is happening and then I shall give you the solution. `Dsolve` (and `Solve` also) return a table of all possible solutions. For your case the solution is unique, so it is a table with one element. You can check it by

```
sig[t] /. sol1
```

You see the answer is `{5. t}` not `5. t`. When you put this this with `Plot` there is no problem. It is like

```
Plot[{5. t},{t,0,100}]
```

and it gives a nice plot. But with `ParametricPlot` it doesn't go so smooth. In this case the structure should be like

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t],y[t]},{t,0,100}]
```

but in your case it becomes like

```
ParametricPlot[{{x[t]},y[t]},{t,0,100}]
                 \_^_/
```

and hence it fails to plot anything.

The **solution** is quite easy. Use

```
sig[t] /. sol1[[1]]
```

You see now it returns `5. t`. And your `ParametricPlot` will give

```
strn[t] = t*0.00025;
modulus = 20000;
sol1 = DSolve[{D[strn[t], t] == D[sig[t], t]/modulus, sig[0] == 0}, sig[t], t];
ParametricPlot[{sig[t] /. sol1[[1]], strn[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: plot]

This will be more clear if you use a second order differential (or quadratic) equation. There you will have two solutions and then you have to specify which solution you want to use `sol1[[1]]` or `sol1[[2]]` for a single plotting.